# Zsh: Passing multiple arguments to command (ls) from a variable ($LS_OPTIONS)

Tags: zsh, environment-variables, arguments

I am trying to customize `ls` command adding arguments to `$LS_OPTIONS`

The `ls` alias and `LS_OPTIONS` are defined in the default config file:

```
export LS_OPTIONS='--color=auto'
...
alias ls='ls $LS_OPTIONS'
```

I redefined `$LS_OPTIONS` at the end of `.zshrc` file:

```
export LS_OPTIONS='--color=auto --group-directories-first'
```

after sourcing `.zshrc`, I type `ls` and get:

```
ls: unrecognized option '--group-directories-first --color=auto'
Try 'ls --help' for more information.
```

clearly the whole variable is passed as a single argument, which is wrong.
I  tried:

```
unalias ls 
ls $LS_OPTIONS
```

and got the same error.

In bash it works correctly:

```
bash
unalias ls
ls $LS_OPTIONS
#-> list of files
```

Please can help?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19530/expanding-variables-in-zsh and/or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218511/how-do-you-use-variables-with-values-containing-spaces-in-a-z-shell-zsh-script

Answer (score 2):

`zsh` wants you to use `array`.

```bash
LS_OPTIONS=(--color=auto --group-directories-first)
ls $LS_OPTIONS
```